# Query Excel worksheet in MS-Access VBA (using ADODB recordset)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'd like to query an Excel worksheet in VBA **and** specify conditions.

The simple query `"SELECT * FROM [PCR$]"` works perfectly, but I don't know how to add a WHERE clause.

I tried `cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PCR$] WHERE ([B1] IS NOT NULL)"` but then it complains about missing parameters.

This is the complete code:

```
Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn2 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd2 As New ADODB.Command
Dim intField As Integer
Dim strFile As String

strFile = fncOpenFile
If strFile = "" Then Exit Sub

With cnn2
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & strFile & "'; " & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
    .Open
End With

Set cmd2.ActiveConnection = cnn2
cmd2.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PCR$]"
rs2.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs2.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rs2.LockType = adLockOptimistic

rs2.Open cmd2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your connection string you say

```
 Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes
```

Which means that the first row will be treated as the header, no matter what it contains. If you want to use F1, F2 etc, say

```
Excel 8.0;HDR=No
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you have the `HDR=Yes` option, the column name should be the data in the first row.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934