# VBA - Create ADODB.Recordset from the contents of a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

I am working on an Excel application that queries a SQL database. The queries can take a long time to run (20-40 min). If I've miss-coded something it can take a long time to error or reach a break point. I can save the results to a sheet fine, it's when I am working with the record sets that things can blow up.

Is there a way to load the data into a ADODB.Recordset when I'm debugging to skip querying the database (after the first time)?

Would I use something like this?

[Query Excel worksheet in MS-Access VBA (using ADODB recordset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086234/query-excel-worksheet-in-ms-access-vba-using-adodb-recordset)

Comment: That looks fine to me, watch out for the connection string if you are using a version greater than 2003.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Was hoping for a smidgen of code or a link to a more explicit example though. Arguably, my question did request basically a yes/no response. My fault. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to install the MDAC to get the msado15.dll and once I had it I added a reference to it from (on Win7 64bit):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll

Then I created a function to return an ADODB.Recordset object by passing in a sheet name that exists in the currently active workbook. Here's the code for any others if they need it, including a Test() Sub to see if it works:

```
Public Function RecordSetFromSheet(sheetName As String)

Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnx As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

    'setup the connection
    '[HDR=Yes] means the Field names are in the first row
    With cnx
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'; " & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
        .Open
    End With
    
    'setup the command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "$]"
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    
    'open the connection
    rst.Open cmd
    
    'disconnect the recordset
    Set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    
    'cleanup
    If CBool(cmd.State And adStateOpen) = True Then
        Set cmd = Nothing
    End If
     
    If CBool(cnx.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnx.Close
    Set cnx = Nothing
    
    '"return" the recordset object
    Set RecordSetFromSheet = rst

End Function

Public Sub Test()

Dim rstData As ADODB.Recordset
Set rstData = RecordSetFromSheet("Sheet1")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rstData

End Sub
```

The Sheet1 data:
Field1 Field2 Field3
Red    A    1
Blue    B    2
Green    C    3

What should be copied to Sheet2:
Red    A    1
Blue    B    2
Green    C    3

This is saving me a HUGE amount of time from querying against SQL every time I want to make a change and test it out...

--Robert

Comment: The sheet data wouldn't line up the way I wanted it, looks like carriage returns are eliminated from comments. Hopefully it makes sense anyway.

Comment: `cmd.State` is not a bitmask, just use `cmd.State = adStateOpen`

Comment: @robault, building tables in question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support and https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to use `rs.Save "filename"` and `rs.Open "filename"` to serialize client-side recordsets to files.

Comment: Good point, that might work but I haven't tried it. I was able to use the solution in the VBA Function above. Thanks for the tip though. This might have done the trick just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to get a `Recordset` from a `Range` would be to create and `XMLDocument` from the target `Range` and open the `Recordset` from that document using the `Range.Value()` property.

```vb
' Creates XML document from the target range and then opens a recordset from the XML doc.
' @ref Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
' @ref Microsoft XML, v6.0
Public Function RecordsetFromRange(ByRef target As Range) As Recordset
        ' Create XML Document from the target range.
        Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
        Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
        doc.LoadXML target.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)

        ' Open the recordset from the XML Doc.
        Set RecordsetFromRange = New ADODB.Recordset
        RecordsetFromRange.Open doc
End Function
```

Make sure to set a reference to both `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library` and `Microsoft XML, v6.0` if you want to use the example above. You could also change this function to late binding if so desired.

#### Example call

```vb
' Sample of using `RecordsetFromRange`
' @author Robert Todar <robert@roberttodar.com>
Private Sub testRecordsetFromRange()
    ' Test call to get rs from Range.
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = RecordsetFromRange(Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

    ' Loop all rows in the recordset
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF
        ' Sample if the fields `Name` and `ID` existed in the rs.
        ' Debug.Print rs.Fields("Name"), rs.Fields("ID")

        ' Move to the next row in the recordset
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```