# Advice on what methodology/data structure/algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, graph-theory

I'm looking for some advice on methodology/data structure/algorithmic approach for a problem I'm trying to solve.

I am writing a custom spreadsheet application in VBA. The spreadsheet is a labor scheduling & quote generation document. The user enters basic labor scheduling information which is then used to generate multiple different worksheets/documents with the source data presented in a variety of different layouts/formats.

To be honest Excel is the wrong application for this but it's what the users wanted and are comfortable with and I know VBA quite well so it's what I'm stuck with.

The key data the user inputs is in the below format, essentially an entry for each daily work call for each role.

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ QTY ║ ROLE   ║      START     ║       END      ║ DESCRIPTION       ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/15/17 08:00a ║ 6/15/17 04:00p ║ Travel to Prep    ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/16/17 08:00a ║ 6/16/17 06:00p ║ Prep              ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/17/17 08:00a ║ 6/17/17 07:00p ║ Prep              ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3   ║ Rigger ║ 6/18/17 06:00a ║ 6/18/17 05:00p ║ Travel to Install ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3   ║ Rigger ║ 6/19/17 08:00a ║ 6/20/17 01:00a ║ Install           ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3   ║ Rigger ║ 6/20/17 10:00a ║ 6/20/17 08:00p ║ Install           ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3   ║ Rigger ║ 6/21/17 07:00a ║ 6/21/17 04:00p ║ Travel Home       ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Typically the data is multiple roles across multiple days and will often have multiple instances of a role on some (but not necessarily all) days.

One of the data manipulations the code does is to take this source data and re-formats it into a summary table so that the user can assign names at a later date once people are assigned. It's also the basis for various other individual work-call sheets and calculating number of flights/hotel-nights etc.

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ NAME ║ ROLE      ║ START   ║ END     ║ DESCRIPTION                           ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Rigger #1 ║ 6/15/17 ║ 6/21/17 ║ Trav | Prep | Trav | Install | Trav   ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Rigger #2 ║ 6/18/17 ║ 6/21/17 ║ Trav | Install | Trav                 ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Rigger #3 ║ 6/18/17 ║ 6/21/17 ║ Trav | Install | Trav                 ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Sound     ║ 6/15/17 ║ 6/22/17 ║ Trav | Install | Trav                 ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Crew #1   ║ 6/17/17 ║ 6/30/17 ║ Trav | Install | Show | Strike | Trav ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Crew #2   ║ 6/17/17 ║ 6/22/17 ║ Trav | Install | Trav                 ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║      ║ Crew #2   ║ 6/26/17 ║ 6/30/17 ║ Trav | Strike | Trav                  ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I convert the source data from n-qty rows into n x rows of qty 1 and append an instance count to the role value if there are multiple instances. This is currently achieved by looping the data array a few times and manipulating the data accordingly - psuedocode below

```
create 2-dimensional DataArray from source data

Loop DataArray
    generate list of unique Roles
    Sum all Qty values
Next

Create 2-dimensional OutputArray
    size rows to match Sum of all Qty values in DataArray
    size cols to match DataArray cols

//determine which UniqueRoles have multiple work instances
For Each UniqueRole in DataArray

    Loop DataArray
        Count unique Start Dates for UniqueRole
        Sum Qty values for UniqueRole
    Next

    If Sum of UniqueRole Qtys > Count of UniqueRole unique Start Dates Then
        Add UniqueRole to MultpleInstanceList
    End If

Next UniqueRole

//copy data into new array, expand all n-qty rows into n x rows of 1 qty
Loop DataArray

    Do While DataArray CurrentRow Qty Value > 1
        Copy DataArray CurrentRow to OutputArray NewRow
        Overwrite Qty value in OutputArray = 1
        Reduce DataArray CurrentRow Qty value by 1
    Loop

    Copy DataArray CurrentRow to OutputArray NewRow

Next

//append count to Roles with multiple instances
For Each UniqueRole in MultipleInstanceList

    Loop OutputArray
        generate list of unique Start Dates for current UniqueRole
    Next

    For Each StartDate in UniqueStartDates

        Loop OutputArray
            generate row index list for matching UniqueRole AND StartDate
        Next

        initialize counter k = 1

        For Each Row in RowIndexList
            OutputArray(Row) Role value = Role value & " #" & k
            k = k + 1
        Next Row

    Next StartDate

Next UniqueRoleVaue
```

I then generate the summary table from the expanded array.

This works fine for simple cases however when there are complex configurations it can produce inconsistant results when appending the instance number relative to the description value e.g…

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ QTY ║ ROLE   ║ START           ║ END            ║ DESCRIPTION       ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/15/17 08:00a  ║ 6/15/17 04:00p ║ Travel to Prep    ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/16/17 08:00a  ║ 6/16/17 06:00p ║ Prep              ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/17/17 08:00a  ║ 6/17/17 07:00p ║ Prep              ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3   ║ Rigger ║ 6/18/17 06:00a  ║ 6/18/18 05:00p ║ Travel to Install ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3   ║ Rigger ║ 6/19/17 08:00a  ║ 6/19/17 06:00p ║ Install           ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Rigger ║ 6/20/17 07:00a  ║ 6/20/17 04:00p ║ Travel Home       ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 2   ║ Rigger ║ 6/20/17 08:00a  ║ 6/20/17 06:00p ║ Install           ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 2   ║ Rigger ║ 6/21/17 07:00a  ║ 6/21/17 04:00p ║ Travel Home       ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

…will output…

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ROLE      ║ START   ║ END     ║ DESCRIPTION                                ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Rigger #1 ║ 6/15/17 ║ 6/21/17 ║ Trav | Prep | Trav | Install | Trav | Trav ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Rigger #2 ║ 6/18/17 ║ 6/21/17 ║ Trav | Install | Trav                      ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Rigger #3 ║ 6/18/17 ║ 6/20/17 ║ Trav | Install                             ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

This entire operation occurs multiple times during normal document use and if the data order changes (which is possible) it can also produce inconsistant results between operations.

I'd prefer not to have to sort the source array as part of the operation as it's an expensive process which adds noticeable lag once the table gets into 10s of rows, even when using merge-sort or quick-sort.

I'm trying to keep this process as optimized as possible; a lot of other outputs use this expanded array, some of which effectively provide live feedback therefore the operation runs every time the user inputs data.

The list of possible descriptions that the user can select is pre-determined

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║ Travel to Prep        ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel & Prep         ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Prep                  ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Prep & Travel         ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel to Install     ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel & Install      ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Install               ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel to Show        ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Rehearsal             ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Show                  ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Show & Dismantle      ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel to Dismantle   ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Dismantle             ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel Home           ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Travel to Site Survey ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Site Survey           ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ Dark Day              ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

I *think* this is effectively a directed graph, the edges all have a direction (most are one way) and some nodes can self-loop. I have built an adjacency matrix for the above list as this seems to be a logical way to determine if the order of assignment is valid.

Is there is an efficient way to ensure all paths for a specific role are valid traversal paths and how best to re-assign the role instance numbers if one or more paths are not valid?

Or is it possible to use the sub-set of description values at each level of the path traversal during the expansion operation to ensure role instance numbers are assigned correctly to begin with?

Is there a particular area of graph theory that I should be looking at? Are graphs the right approach here? Is there an alternative approach that would work/be more efficient?

Any advice/help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: I read the description 3 times, but what problem are you actually trying to solve? From your data in, what is your expected data out? Many times if you can explain your problem to a stranger you will have the solution. This reads like you are stuck in a how and forgot the what. Can you give some examples of input, good output, wrong output?

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the following quote:

> I'd prefer not to have to sort the source array as part of the
>   operation as it's an expensive process which adds noticeable lag once
>   the table gets into 10s of rows, even when using merge-sort or
>   quick-sort.

I notice that you're referring to your source as an array.  So are users entering information into a sheet range and from there you use VBA to load the data into an array?  If so, I wonder if you are aware of Recordsets in VBA.  From my recollection, they're not exactly straightforward to read data into, but once the data is in, then you can run a SQL query on it.  This is not immune to performance issues, but I think you'll do better than taking a hit after 10's of records.  And you'll probably not have to worry about sorting methodologies. If you're not familiar with SQL, I'd say it's definitely worth the time given the things you're trying to do.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484516/vba-create-adodb-recordset-from-the-contents-of-a-spreadsheet) a guy who did it.  He had a different reason for doing it, but you would be able to apply it in your case.

By the way, if your users are comfortable with Excel, then with work, they may still be comfortable with MS Access.  No installation of new software, you can do SQL without loading data into new objects, and you can work with forms and develop reports more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Well, deploy software integrated in Office product, mainly Excel, is sometimes the dream for the users. That is not meaning that you should write code into a especific spreadsheet file (.xlsm).

You have other options that could improve the segregation and easily could be translated into others solutions. Some possibilities:

1)  ExcelAddIn in VBA:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx

2)  ExcelAddIn in .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx

or even,

3) XLL, if the performance is an issue (does not seems to be your case) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687829.aspx

I hope that helps!