# Importing from Excel - Header is not on row 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, import-from-excel, oledbcommand

Is there some simple way I am missing to import an Excel worksheet into a datatable using an OleDBConnection and change what row the header is located on? I have HDR=YES in my connection string and that works great when header is on row 1 but the header is actually going to need to be on row 3. I am using the following CommandText:

```
SELECT [headercol1name], [headercol2name], [headercol3name] FROM [sheetname]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a range: [How can I programmatically import Excel data into an Access table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572064/how-can-i-programmatically-import-excel-data-into-an-access-table)

"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A3:G65536]" will only return records for used range, though I did not test very carefully.

Comment: This appears to have worked correctly! I knew it was something simple. Do you know if there is a better way to say from A3 to the end of the spreadsheet other than G65536?

Comment: No, I don't, unless you have some sort of automation, or want to run the query twice, once on the sheet without a range to check the number of rows, once to use that count (minus unused top row count of course) with the range.

Comment: I should also add that 65536 is not the toatl count for more recent versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, neither the `HDR` parameter or the schema.ini file allow anything but the first row to be the header row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx